# SQL replace function doesn't work on NHibernate

Tags: sql, .net, oracle, nhibernate, regexp-replace

I'm using the NHibernate to do a simple native sql query, with the replace function, but it doesn't work.
the query is like this:
`select replace(nome, 'á', 'a') from municipios`

with this query, the result still returning with the 'á' character.
the query execute corretly diretly on DB, only with the NHibernate, it show this odd bahavior.
other replace function like `REGEXP_REPLACE` and `TRANSLATE` not work too.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

i'm using Oracle DataBase 19c, NHibernate 3.1.0.4000 and .NET  4.5.2.

i tried to use the `REGEXP_REPLACE` and `TRANSLATE` functions, but got the same bahavior.

Comment: Why are you using NHibernate if you want to run a native query in the first place? Why not use ADO.NET directly? There are no objects to map and since you use product-specific functions, no point in abstracting the database provider.

Comment: Are you sure that the character is `á` and not the character `a` followed by a diacritic character `ˊ`? What is the output if you `SELECT DUMP(nome) FROM municipios`?

Comment: I suspect wrong nls parameters...

Comment: @MT0 this query return `Typ=1 Len=15: 65,98,97,100,105,97,32,100,101,32,71,111,105,225,115`

the "á" character is the penultimate value `225`, it's the correct  decimal value for the character "á".

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov the query `SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER ='NLS_LANGUAGE'` returns `AMERICAN`

Comment: maybe an encoding issue, the nome column seems to have ansi but the query might be in unicode